# Accept days & convert it into equivalent no. of years, months, weeks & remaining days

Tags: c, converters, formula, modulo

I am actually TRYING to solve on how will I make these formulas right on c programming. These are few lines of my code.

My program is supposed to get an input from the user which is a day and give its equiv. in years,months,weeks, and days.

So for example I have 730 days.
If im going to convert it in years with months, weeks...
it will be THERE ARE 2 YEARS, O MONTHS, 0, WEEKS, AND 0 DAYS (not sure if this is right).
Another example, I have 402 days then it will be there is 1 YEAR, 1 MONTH, 1 WEEK, 0 DAYS left(Am I right?).

The code that i had for "month" before was
    month =(days /365)/30;
and changed it to
    month =(days %365)/30;

Last time when I inputted a number, the answers were right then when i entered different numbers, it seems to be wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void  main( )
{
    int  days ,yr,mn,wk,d;
    printf("Enter the no of days");
    scanf("%d",&days);

    yr = days /365;

    mn =(days /365)/30;


    printf("Years= %d \t Months=  %d \t Weeks =%d \t days = %d",yr,mn,wk,d);

    getch();
 }
```

So I really am having a hard time solving for the right formula. I hope that I can get some little help on what is wrong with the formula for not getting the right outputs. I must use mod for this.

Comment: So each year has 365 days and each month has 30 days?

Comment: Well, consider a simple input. Let's say 50. Taking the number of weeks, `50/365` is 0, so yeah.

Comment: @chris I edited my title and code. With my formulas. Are they right? I tried it and im not sure.

Comment: Test a number like I just did. Hint: 50 still doesn't work.

Comment: @chris I tried different number but still no. I also tried to changed the month to this formula  mn =(days %365)/30; but still no. Im confused.

Comment: Instead of having complicated expressions, break it down into functions. Something like `getCompleteYears`, `getCurrentYearDays`, and so on for the other things. Then it becomes English to get what you want. For example, months is `getCompleteMonths(getCurrentYearDays(days))`.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode my problem is actually converting a day to its year with months, weeks, and days and not each of them like if i give 365 days, ill have 12 months, 1 year. no.

Comment: Yeahp, modifying my answer as I comment

Comment: @chris I finally solved the year and month but my problem is is still dont know how to make it work on the remaining DAYS AND WEEKS. PLEEASE HELP.

Comment: You can check a similar example here [C program to convert days to years, weeks and days](http://codeforwin.blogspot.in/2015/06/c-program-to-convert-days-into-years-weeks-days.html)

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is: for each successively smaller unit of time, you need to be working with the number of days *left over* from those you have already accounted for.  In the example of 50 days, there are no years, and 1 month; once you've accounted for the month, there are still 50-30=20 days left to account for.

So the algorithm would be: for each successively smaller unit of time, compute how many of that unit there are, and subtract out the number of days covered by that (leaving the days left to account for).

Comment: Yes I actually tried doing the subtraction thing but Im supposed to have MODULO formula. Will the mod will still be present? (im very sorry im still new at this)

Comment: I tried a temp variable, and now im confused on how will i continue with the weeks and remaining days using modulo. yr = days /365;
    temp=days-365;
    mn=temp/30;

Comment: @user3767918: If you do `yr = days /365;` then you've already accounted for lots of days. To find the number days that weren't accounted for by the years calculation, you'd do `days = days % 365;`.

Comment: @Brendan tried it but my days went a lot of number. its not right.

Comment: @Brendan I finally solved the year and month but my problem is is still dont know how to make it work on the remaining DAYS AND WEEKS. PLEEASE HELP.

Comment: @Scott Hunter I finally solved the year and month but my problem is is still dont know how to make it work on the remaining DAYS AND WEEKS. PLEEASE HELP.

Comment: @ScottHunter  I finally solved the year and month but my problem is is still dont know how to make it work on the remaining DAYS AND WEEKS. PLEEASE HELP.

Comment: user3767918: You can take Brendan's solution, but use `%` instead of subtraction for each computation of the remaining days.  Or you can think of it as doing what you did for years and months, but using the number of days in a month/week or week/day.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have a solution:

```
long yr = days/365;
days -= yr * 365;

long mn = days/30;
days -= mn * 30;

long wk = days/7;
days -= wk * 7;

// days now has remainder of days
```

Comment: But I actually have to give out a day for example 50 days and its equivalent year is 0, month is 1, 2 weeks, and 6 days. equivalent.

Comment: Let me modify my answer then :L Sorry, I must not have read the question correctly

Comment: thank you i will wait but also while waiting ill try to figure out my mistake

Comment: I finally solved the year and month but my problem is is still dont know how to make it work on the remaining DAYS AND WEEKS. PLEEASE HELP.

Comment: Sorry, I actually had a working solution but I got a floating point exception for any value less than a year D: